# How to create a matrix from a set of existing grouped vectors?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, statistics, data-generation

I have data like this:

```
X1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
X2<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
X3<-c(0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4,0.4)
```

I want to create another dataset (probably a matrix?) from the existing one in a way that I get the following desire output:

|X1 | X2 | X3|

|1  |0   |0.02|

|2  |1  |0.1|

|3  |0    |0.4|

P.S: And how can I do that if X2 and X3 have different values for each group of X1? Like below:

```
X1<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
X2<-c(0,1,6,3,0,5,1,4,0,2,4,7,3)
X3<-c(0.02,0.04,0.01,0.09,0.02,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.2,0.1,0.4)
```

Comment: You can use `unique(data.frame(X1, X2, X3))`.  For the second case, not sure about your expected output

Comment: @akrun thanks!! Ir helped! for the second case, Im not sure if I can even do such a thing because I have different values? That is why I have no pre-imagination of the expected output

Comment: You could have a `list` column in a data.frame i.e. `library(dplyr);data.frame(X1, X2, X3) %>% group_by(X1) %>% summarise(across(everything(), ~ list(unique(.))))` or may be use `xtabs(X3 ~ X1 + X2)`